# How to query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
    SID CHAR(4),
    NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(20),
    PHONE VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(SID)
);

CREATE TABLE CLUB(
    CID CHAR(4),
    CNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CID)
);

CREATE TABLE EVENT(
    EID CHAR(4),
    ENAME VARCHAR(50),
    EDATE TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(EID)
);


CREATE TABLE MEMBERSHIP(
    SID CHAR(4),
    CID CHAR(4),
    SEMESTER VARCHAR(10),
    MYEAR CHAR(4),
    FEE DECIMAL(5,2),
    FOREIGN KEY(SID) REFERENCES STUDENT(SID),
    FOREIGN KEY(CID) REFERENCES CLUB(CID),
    PRIMARY KEY(SID,CID,SEMESTER,MYEAR)
);

CREATE TABLE HOLDEVENT(
    EID CHAR(4),
    CID CHAR(4),
    MEMFEE DECIMAL(5,2),
    NONMEMFEE DECIMAL(5,2),
    FOREIGN KEY(EID) REFERENCES EVENT(EID),
    FOREIGN KEY(CID) REFERENCES CLUB(CID),
    PRIMARY KEY(EID,CID)
);


CREATE TABLE JOINEVENT(
    EID CHAR(4),
    SID CHAR(4),
    FEE DECIMAL(5,2),
    FOREIGN KEY(EID) REFERENCES EVENT(EID),
    FOREIGN KEY(SID) REFERENCES STUDENT(SID),
    PRIMARY KEY(EID,SID)
);
```

How can I write queries that:

1. output names of all pairs of clubs that have organised more than 5 events together?
2. output the sid of any any students who is member with XYZ in every semester since fall 1990?

```
With temp(sem,tyear) as (select semester,n from (select unique semester from Membership),(select n from( select rownum n from dual connect by level <= Extract(year from sysdate)) where n >= 1990))        
select distinct sid from Membership M1 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select * from temp WHERE NOT EXISTS
(select * from Membership M2 WHERE M1.sid = M2.sid AND M2.myear=temp.tyear AND M2.semester=temp.sem AND M2.cid in (select cid from Club where cname='Chess Club')));
```

Please help to identify weak entities in this schema.

Comment: You should have put down your effort as well.. its the first step towards learning :)

Comment: I tried but dont how to deal with every sem since 1990. I tried alot before posting here. I am not asking for exact posting the logic will be more then helpful. think twice bfore giving negative flag

Comment: Can u please describe query #02 , what do u mean by member with XYZ in every semester... what relationship are u focuing on!

Comment: use http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ to show your data and expected result

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist XYZ is club name for eg john kerry is member of XYZ club since fall 1990 for every semester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you could go about the two tasks:

1. Query HOLDEVENT twice, so you get records with an event, an organizing club and another organizing club. Think of a way not to get both event = "Event 1" | club1 = "Club A" | club2 = "Club B" and event = "Event 1" | club1 = "Club B" | club2 = "Club A". Then group by club1 and club2 and filter such that you get only those pairs having organized more than five events.
2. Count the semesters each student was member since 1990. Compare to the actual number of semesters since 1990.

Comment: with temp(sid,total) as (select sid,count(*) from Membership where ((myear between '1991' and Extract(year from sysdate)) or (semester='Fall' and myear='1990'))and cid in (select cid from Club where cname='Chess Club') group by sid)
select sid from temp where total='47';